# Calculate maximum font size in datagridview when cell content fully showing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` (Winform C#) with predefined height and width, sizes of the all columns are also predefined and fixed. I can define maximum length of text. I want to define maximum font size when content in the all grid cells is fully shown.

For example I have some grids with data "Hello World" in some cells. When font is 18px then user only sees "Hello ..." but if font is 16px then user can see all words "Hello World".

In other words, I would like to programmatically define maximum font size by text length and grid size when content is not hidden. How to do this?

Comment: Do you want all Cells to have the same font size?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try comparing the ActualWidth properties of the column and the Label or TextBlock whatever displays your text. Reduce the font size until the ActualWidth of the Label or TextBlock is less than the column's.